# How to quickly setup a gradient mesh for annulus-like shapes in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient-mesh

I usually encounter annulus-like shapes such as the one shown below:

[image]

I want to create a gradient mesh out of this array of discrete patches. However, `Adobe Illustrator` can only create rectangular gradient mesh. I had to fudge the mesh to this annulus. I'm wondering is there a good way to create a gradient mesh that cover this annulus shape and so that the mesh grid more or less follow the grid of the annulus?

Comment: it is not possible in illustrator, you may need to start the project using any 3D software doing the job and project the result into Illustrator for recoloring.

Answer (score 11):

This is what I find to be an acceptable solution. First, create a gradient mesh to a box as follows.

[image]

Second, drag every other box to a suitable location.

[image]

Third, rotate each box to a suitable angle.

[image]

Fourth, drag each vertex to a suitable location.

[image]

Fifth, pick up color for each vertex from the original figure.

[image]

Sixth, use the original figure to create a mask for the mesh.

[image]

Although it is stupid, it will eventually get what I want.

Comment: Will someone please adjust the size of the figures for me...

Comment: I just did it for you. Nice answer!

Comment: I started to write "it's easier if you start with standard rectangles or ellipses then transform them." Then I realized explaining may take more time than I had. Good answer to your own question +1.

Comment: @Yisela Thank you so much. Now I know how to do it in the future.

Comment: @Scott Thanks. I think you are suggesting the same solution. I somehow expect someone to write a script for me XD.

Comment: don't get your hopes up, unfortunately, Mesh Points are not accessible to scripting :(

Comment: @CarlosCanto I know.......

Comment: Going full circle +1.

Comment: Troy, have you tried Mesh Tormentor? I haven't, I just know it exists http://www.meshtormentor.com/